# Dynamically add css to page via javascript

Tags: javascript, css

I'm making a widget that will be added to external websites, and I have made a page that generates css for them to style it (text color, background color, font size, etc). I end up with a textarea filled with css for them to copy/paste to their website.

Is there a way to add this css to the current page in order to have a live preview?

Answer (score 177):

If you want to add CSS as text

```
var style = document.createElement('style');
style.innerHTML = 'content';
document.head.appendChild(style);
```

If you want to add a CSS file

```
var link = document.createElement('link');
link.setAttribute('rel', 'stylesheet');
link.setAttribute('href', 'css/my.css');
document.head.appendChild(link);
```

Comment: JavaScript allows not to put `;` at the end, but it can lead to unexpected behaviour and is considered bad practice.

Comment: Is there any npm package / js library to do this where I can just pass a CSS JSON object?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know a library like that.

Comment: Does this still work even if the css is loaded right after page load?

Comment: It worked for me in my environment but it is always better to try in your particular case.

Comment: I had to use `innerText` instead of `innerHTML` to get this to work in Chrome.

Comment: you can just do `document.head` instead of `document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0]`

Comment: With modern linters... `;` have been deprecated in modern dev workflows/tooling, depending on your environment

Comment: That's wonderful. I didn't use them in my answer but those Crockford followers had been attacking this post for several years every week, demanding semicolons. Finally they made while I wasn't online to for some time. Anyway, I am happy that common sense prevailed.

Comment: @RayFoss what do you mean by modern? for example in Google Earth Engine Editor it demands it

Comment: @FlashThunder The best guage of guidelines are the ESLint rule sets in use... the biggest ones like AirBnB, Standard and most Typescript ones dropped the `;`. The reasoning is you need to know when you "need" one even if you use them, so why use them. There is a good slide show on it from the maker of Vue, Evan You. http://slides.com/evanyou/semicolons

Answer (score 17):

I have traditionally appended a `<style>` block when doing elements.

```
var style_rules = [];

style_rules.push("#" + myElemId + " { /* Rules */ } ");
/* ... */

var style = '<style type="text/css">' + style_rules.join("\n") + "</style>";
$("head").append(style);
```

An important thing to note is that because you don't know what any of the existing styles is, or what `id`'s might conflict on the page, it's very useful to keep track of your id's inside your JavaScript application, then using those to populate the injected `<style>` block. I also tend to run my names through a prefix function to ensure that the generic names of `wrapper`, and `unit` do not conflict (they are turned into something like `myunique_wrapper` and `myunique_unit`.

Incorporating a basic CSS reset like `#myWrapper {margin: 0; padding: 0}` can be a decent starting platform for building your own custom styles.

Addressing your unique case, a live preview so to speak, I would designate a div with standard elements. Then when they click "update" read in the rules and append them to the head. If you want to negate any residual effects from past rules you can remove the last `<style>` element or better yet give your `<style>` element an id. I'm not sure if that kind of selection would work, but it should.

Comment: I would recommend you adjust your answer to exclude the use of jQuery as the OP did not mention the use of it, nor did they tag the question with jquery

Comment: @Jondavid: I make one call with jQuery, which is actually just as easily done with pure JavaScript. Simple DOM manipulation. My answer uses jQuery, if the OP would like to not use jQuery then he can of course modify that one small portion of my example code.

Comment: Then why wouldn't you just adjust your answer to conform to the OP's specifications?

Comment: @jondavid: The OP has neglected to give any specifications.

Comment: jquery is super common, and its not the responsibility of answers to try to guess at the tools at an OP's disposal. When in doubt, recommend what you would do. I certainly wouldn't recommend using pure dom manipulation..

Comment: @BT and Josh-K The convention is that unless OP added jQuery as a Tag, then jquery is not part of the specification.  jondavidjohn is correct. 12 years later the plain JS answer is more useful than the jQuery one.

Answer (score 7):

```js
var element = document.createElement('style');
element.setAttribute('type', 'text/css');

if ('textContent' in element) {
  element.textContent = css;
} else {
  element.styleSheet.cssText = css;
}

document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(element);
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you add a `style` tag to the DOM, with the contents of the text-area in it? You may want to give it an id so you can change it later.

Answer (score -13):

I recommend you start using a decent framework for your web/JavaScript development, personally I'd go with jQuery.

```
http://api.jquery.com/css/
```

There are some code snippets here that show you how to quickly set css properties for elements.

Comment: I do not consider jQuery a framework, neither do jQuery considers itself a framework, according to jQuery, "jQuery is a fast, small, and feature-rich JavaScript library."

Comment: @AaronC while true, that seems like pedantry in context - the substance of the statement is "I recomment using a [mature and well-maintained reusable code which solves a lot of these common problems], so that you can focus on expressing the big picture semantics of your logic and not the implementation details" - words like "framework" have general abstract composable meanings too, not just their more specific/distinct and thingified/reified meanings that we use in software, and precision of meaning is a value that is relative to the context of what you are actually saying.

Comment: Now I'm sure some of the downvotes here are not because the answer uses "framework" instead of a word which is more appropriate if you project a specific rigid context onto it. But when I see framework in this answer I can immediately tell precisely because "framework" is wrong in that rigid interpretation - that the answerer's meaning is *more abstract and flexible* - the shape of this answer's recommendation applies regardless of whether the reusable code you use is a "library" or "framework" or whatever. And I hope most people downvoting are doing it for other reasons than that wording nit.

Comment: Now having said that, the critique I have for this answer is that when someone asks "how do I do [x]", the answer "use something that already does [x]" is only sometimes appropriate, and in particular is not appropriate if the asker wants to understand the underlying workings, or if the asker has good reason to not reuse the things that already do [x]. (But to be fair to the answer, when people ask or search for "how do I do [x]" it is actually ambiguous - do you want any practical get-it-done answer or the from-the-foundation answer? could be either.)

Comment: @mtraceur I disagree.