# fetch css file after page loads

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've following css files for a hobby project:

- `normalize.css`
- `main.css`
- `viewports.css`
- `bigFile.css`

Now `normalize.css` , `main.css` & `viewports.css` are the 3 files that are loaded on every page visit throughout the website. However `bigFile.css` contains a lots of css styles that are used in internal pages of the website. For now I'm loading these files inside homepage `index.html` like this :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
<link href='//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,300,600' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

I've merged `viewports.css` inside `main.css` and current file size is good. I cannot merge `bigFile.css` since then the size of `main.css` will be large and browser will wait to render it. Also note I'll be using github pages which sets expire headers to almost like 10 minutes , thus making caching state bad for me. And assume user is most likely navigate to next page.

Is there any way I could load `bigfile.css` after the page has loaded successfully so that it saves some time for next page loads. I don't mind using js solution till it has a gracefull fallback on non-js sites (like not loading them till user actually navigates to next page). Also I'm not a big fan of jquery for such a small task. Thanks!

Comment: If i understood correctly, you want `big.css` not to be blocking. Try to place this: `<link rel="stylesheet" property="stylesheet"  href="css/big.css">` inside of the `<body>` instead of the `<head>` (assuming your code delivered is placed here)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4847313/dynamically-add-css-to-page-via-javascript

Comment: @NicoO is that allowed? placing links in body that are intended inside head? and in all browsers?

Comment: [It is, when you set the `itemprop` property](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/semantics.html#the-link-element) in my comment before i did not intended to use `property` but `itemprop`.

Comment: @NicoO then it says `A link element must have either a rel attribute or an itemprop attribute, but not both.` & rel specifies the css part I guess.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can execute a function after page has loaded and put below code inside that function :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
if(document.createStyleSheet) {
  document.createStyleSheet('http://example.com/big.css');
}
else {
  var styles = "@import url('http://example.com/big.css');";
  var newSS=document.createElement('link');
  newSS.rel='stylesheet';
  newSS.href='data:text/css,'+escape(styles);
  document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(newSS);
}
//]]>
```

P.S. Do not forget to call the function only when the page load event completed otherwise same performance issue will be there.

Comment: 1. what is role of CDATA here. 2. `document.createStyleSheet` is for IE?  3. can you explain `@import` , dosen't link contains href? & `escape(styles)` part.

Comment: 4. also what might be a cross browser js event for page load? 5. will it load this css file if I've included it in next page inside head? or in other words , does it resides in cache or not.

Comment: CDATA : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/66837/when-is-a-cdata-section-necessary-within-a-script-tag
createStyleSheet : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms531194(v=vs.85).aspx
I guess you can figure out what is import and escape and their usage.
Page load event : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1795089/how-can-i-detect-dom-ready-and-add-a-class-without-jquery/1795167#1795167

Comment: I know about `@import` and I'm asking how is it different from contructing `newSS` with `href = someurl` and then appending , rather than importing all css and then using `data:text/css` and escaping it. Thanks :)

Comment: From : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10036977/best-way-to-include-css-why-use-import.
So I think, you can just use simple way of including also like you suggested.