# Load CSS only when template is completely done rendering

Tags: jquery, css, render-blocking

I had a link to boostrap stylesheet cdn that was causing some render blocking issues which was performing my site performance according to Google Page Speed Insights. I solved this by only taking the required above the fold bootstrap css and putting it in a 'critic_bootstrap.css' file. When the page is completely rendered, I do want to load that bootstrap CDN anyway for all the other styles that are not above the fold. How can I accomplish this ? I tried appending it to the head of my document in a jquery document.ready function, but it seemed to still cause PSI render blocking issues like it was till being loaded before the page was being rendered.

Comment: Technically, All CSS needs to be rendered before loading the content of page because that's how browser knows how to style what elem

Comment: I guess you're right hah. If I add the who bootstrap CDN at the bottom of the html element, will it render after the above the fold content has been rendered ?

Comment: Try this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30752482/fetch-css-file-after-page-loads?lq=1

Comment: @KannanK gave a better suggestion. good job dude!

Comment: Yeah, tried the solution from your link KannanK and it pumped up the page speed !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('head').append('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap.css">');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
<link rel="preload" href="mystyles.css" as="style" onload="this.rel='stylesheet'">
```

On top of this, if you want to disable [FOUC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flash_of_unstyled_content) for good, add

```
body {
  overflow:hidden;
}
```

to your above the fold CSS and override it in your `async` CSS with

```
body {
  overflow:auto;
}
```

The above is just a summary. If you're interested here's a full post about the method: [Modern Asynchronous CSS Loading](https://www.filamentgroup.com/lab/async-css.html), also containing a polyfill for non-supporting browsers.

> This may not look like a big improvement over other approaches, but one advantage that rel="preload" brings is that supporting browsers will start downloading the file earlier than they would with say, a stylesheet with a non-matching media value.

Also read [Preloading content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Preloading_content). Support for `rel="preload"` is limited to Chrome, Opera and Safari but more will follow (notably Firefox v59). Also, where it's *not supported* it doesn't mean it doesn't work. It only means there's no improvement over using a non-existent `rel` type.

Answer (score 1):

Try to load the css at `$(window).load()` instead of `$(document).ready()`.

for an instance:

```
  $(window).load(function() {
          $('head').append('<link rel="stylesheet" href="common.css" type="text/css" />');
    });
```