# How to load css content as a StyleSheet object?

Tags: javascript, css

I have a css content with xhr load as the following code,

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', 'my.css');
xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (this.readyState == this.DONE) {
        xhr.onreadystatechange = null;
        var style = $('<style/>').html(this.responseText);

        // it will print a dom string in dev console.
        console.log(style[0]);
    }
};
xhr.send();
```

So far I only know how to load the `css` content via `ajax`, 
but I want to let the css content become a `StyleSheet` object, just like to access the `document.styleSheets[n]`,
I can't find any methods to do this, is there a way to do this?

my question is not apply or insert the css rules to the document, my question is how to let the css content string become a StyleSheet object,  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/StyleSheet

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dynamically add css to page via javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4847313/dynamically-add-css-to-page-via-javascript)

Comment: I dont think so, that is not my issue.

Comment: @Jasper using `XMLHttpRequest` you load the content of `my.css` as text.  You need to create an empty style-sheet and set the `cssText`  as described in the duplicate, so why do you think that this won't solve you issue? An additional note: If you load style-sheets that way you either need to make sure that you do not reference other resources like images in the css rules, or that the paths are absolute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can do it as following:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', 'my.css');
xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
  if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) { //4=this.DONE

    xhr.onreadystatechange = null;

    //var style = $('<style/>').html(this.responseText);
    var style = document.createElement('style');
    style.type = 'text/css';
    style.innerHTML = this.responseText;
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(style);

    var cssSheet = style.sheet; //this is the StyleSheet object you need
    var rule = cssSheet.cssRules[0]; //first rule defined in my.css
    alert("first css rule: "+ rule.selectorText + " => " + rule.style.cssText); 
  }
};
xhr.send();
```

The main tip is to use the `sheet` property of the [HTMLStyleElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLStyleElement). it must be accessed only after you have append it to the document.

Comment: thank you for your answer, just the "sheet" property, now, I can do that.