# Injecting CSS into site with Puppeteer

Tags: javascript, node.js, automated-tests, google-chrome-devtools, puppeteer

The site I'm running automated tests on with Puppeteer displays info popups if actions were successful or when something failed. Unfortunately, these popups sometimes cover up buttons my script has to click on. It would be great if I could inject some CSS into the site to hide these popups. Is there an built-in way to do this?

Answer (score 76, accepted):

## addStyleTag:

You can use [page.addStyleTag](https://pptr.dev/api/puppeteer.page.addstyletag) to add some style which will either add a `link` or `style` tag based on your options which can be a `url`, `path` or some css `content`.

```
// url
await page.addStyleTag({url: 'http://example.com/style.css'})

// path, can be relative or absolute path
await page.addStyleTag({path: 'style.css'})

// content
await page.addStyleTag({content: '.body{background: red}'})
```

## evaluateOnNewDocument:

If you want to apply on each page/navigation, you can use [page.evaluateOnNewDocument](https://pptr.dev/api/puppeteer.page.evaluateonnewdocument) with [this snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13883978/6161265).

```
await page.evaluateOnNewDocument(()=>{
  var style = document.createElement('style');
  style.type = 'text/css';
  style.innerHTML = '.body{background: red}'; // the css content goes here
  document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(style);
});
```

Comment: Great! Will this style persist through navigation?

Comment: No, it should add the tag into current page only. We can have `evaluateOnNewDocument` if we want to inject something on each navigation.

Comment: Added example for that.

Comment: Excellent! Thank's a lot!

Comment: For someone with a slow page load:
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
      document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(style);
    }, false);

Answer (score 4):

### page.evaluate()

#### Stylesheet:

You can use [`page.evaluate()`](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pageevaluatepagefunction-args) to inject a stylesheet into the current page using the following method:

```
await page.evaluate(async () => {
  const link = document.createElement('link');
  link.rel = 'stylesheet';
  link.href = 'https://example.com/style.css';
  const promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    link.onload = resolve;
    link.onerror = reject;
  });
  document.head.appendChild(link);
  await promise;
});
```

#### Raw CSS Content:

Alternatively, you can also use [`page.evaluate()`](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pageevaluatepagefunction-args) to inject raw CSS into the current page:

```
await page.evaluate(async () => {
  const style = document.createElement('style');
  style.type = 'text/css';
  const content = `
    #example {
      color: #000;
    }
  `;
  style.appendChild(document.createTextNode(content));
  const promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    style.onload = resolve;
    style.onerror = reject;
  });
  document.head.appendChild(style);
  await promise;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
// add css
const contents = '<table class="class4" style="width: 100%;">
<tbody>
<tr>
    <td style="width: 33.3333%;" class="">
        <br></td>
    <td style="width: 33.3333%;">
        <br></td>
    <td style="width: 33.3333%;">
        <br></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>'

// add css
const cssStyle = `<style>
        .class4 thead tr th,.class4 tbody tr td {
          border-style: solid;
          border-color: coral;
          border-width: 1px;
        }
      </style>
      `;

// add css
const addCssContent = cssStyle + contents;

await page.goto(`data:text/html;base64;charset=UTF-8,${Buffer.from(addCssContent).toString(
            "base64"
          )}`,
          {
            waitUntil: "load",
            timeout: 300000,
            waitFor: 30000,
          }
        );
```

Answer (score -1):

```
await page.$eval('.popup', el => el.style.display = "none")
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.

Comment: not to mention that `style` doesn't exist on `el`.