# Add JS and CSS files on IF/ELSE in html

Tags: javascript

Here is situation

in Dev Environemt , I have to add css and js file like below

```
<script src="../../js/file.js">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../css/file.css">
```

in Production Environment , I have to add same css and js file like below with the change in src attribute

```
<script src="js/file.js">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/file.css">
```

Any solution to do it dynamically instead of manually

Thanks

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4847313/dynamically-add-css-to-page-via-javascript

Comment: it's possible to do client-side, but IMHO it should be handled on server-side instead

Comment: It needs to be done on Client-Side in my case

Answer (score 0):

You can use **PHP** for that.

On the import / include, use `<?php echo dirname(dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'])); ?>`

E.G:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo dirname(dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'])); ?>/css/style.css">
```

`dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'])` will return the path to the current file's directory.

`dirname(dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']));` will return the path before the current file's directory. You can read more about that [here](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.dirname.php), and about `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` [here](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/reserved.variables.server.php).

About using **PHP**, [click here](https://www.ntchosting.com/encyclopedia/scripting-and-programming/php/php-in/).

Comment: You can use `__dirname` instead. Read [here](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/globals.html) and [here](https://www.hostingadvice.com/how-to/nodejs__dirname/).

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that creating the style and script tag on the fly according to an IF.

```
    var link = document.createElement('link');
    link.setAttribute('rel', 'stylesheet');
    link.setAttribute('type', 'text/css');
    if (production)
        link.setAttribute('href', 'css/my.css');
    else
        link.setAttribute('href', 'css/dev_my.css');
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(link);
```